# Netgear XR500 vs ASUS ROG AC5300: Which is the better option with my configuration?

Tags: gaming, wireless, networking, router

After agonizing for days and being an irritant all over Stack Exchange trying to sort out my networking woes, I've narrowed down my current purchase needs to fit one of two routers.  One is the [Netgear Nighthawk Pro XR500](http://www.netgear.com/npg/xr500/), and the other is the [ASUS ROG Rapture GT AC-5300](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/ROG-Rapture-GT-AC5300/).  I've gone through the specs to the point I'm dreaming numbers (again), and I need a little help determining which better fits my use-case considering range, environment, and hardware.

There is a **wired-only** router that is a Ubiquiti unit, currently positioned in the basement. I'm using its firewall and it is connected to wall jacks down there, as well.

The wireless router this purchase would replace is two stories above.  Connecting devices on that floor include one hardline connection, one wireless AC (AD is possible, but a wall exists) within 2 feet, and one N connection roughly 35 feet away.

Connecting devices one floor down include two Steam Links, a laptop, an XBox 360, and a smart television.  These are all within 20 feet of the router, as they are almost directly beneath it. All connect via N or AC.  There is also a multifunction printer on Wireless N which is further from the router, across the house, on this floor.

Connecting devices two floors down not using the wired connection are a laptop and another XBox 360.  The range at this point is 45 feet or so.  All of these are G or N connections.  I'm not hoping for a lot here and may put a second wireless unit down there on its own subnet or try to repeat on the same SID.

If the purchase renders the use of the Ubiquiti obsolete, I would like to remove it from the network, but I really like its firewall.

Given the above, which of the two routers would most suit my needs?

Comment: Since you already have an Ubiquiti router, why not just add an Ubiquiti AP or 2?  I'm not convinced (based on your other question about your setup) that a single consumer all-in-one will be adequate for you 3 story cult-house.

Comment: The Ubiquiti itself has no wireless capabilities, so I'd need an AP to essentially stop at each floor.  I don't mind that, but the AC APs are $100 a piece, have a bit lower connection speed (which is probably just a more honest listing than most, actually) and I'm concerned about losing the physical port for the second floor machine.  I also don't have a PoE router; only one port is PoE. It's a good idea though....i'll add that to my options

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just curious if that were an option.  I see what you are trying to accomplish, I'm not sure I have the answer.  Hopefully someone does as I like your question.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's an option the more I look into it.  I'm just concerned that all of those devices will be too taxing on the small Ubiquiti router, if my current router is overheating.

Comment: I'd still lean toward having a router and an AP or two, versus 1 do-everything device, just because of wall and floor.  If your current router is having issues...maybe a Google WiFi or a similar mesh network could work as well, and isn't overly expensive.